# Following memory allocation in gdb

Tags: linux, memory-management, gdb

Why is memory consumption jumping unpredictably as I step through a program in the `gdb` debugger?  I'm trying to use gdb to find out why a program is using far more memory than it should, and it's not cooperating.

I step through the source code while monitoring process memory usage, but I can't find what line(s) allocate the memory for two reasons:

1. Reported memory usage only jumps up in increments of (usually, but not always exactly) 64 MB.  I suspect I'm seeing the effects of some memory manager I don't know about which reserves 64 MB at a time and masks multiple smaller allocations.
2. The jump doesn't happen at a consistent location in code.  Not only does it occur on different lines during different gdb runs; it also sometimes happens in illogical places like the closing bracket of a (c++) function.  Is it possible that gdb itself is affecting memory allocations?

Any ideas/suggestions for more effective tools to help me drill down to the code lines that are really responsible for these memory allocations?

Here's some relevant system info:  I'm running  x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu version 7.2-64.el6-5.2 on a virtual CentOS Linux machine under Windows.  The program is built on a remote server via a complicated build script, so tracking down exactly what options were used at any point is itself a bit of a chore.  I'm monitoring memory usage both with the `top` utility ("virt" or virtual memory column) and by reading the real-time monitoring file `/proc/<pid>/status`, and they agree.  Since this program uses a large suite of third-party libraries, there may be one or more overridden `malloc()` functions involved somewhere that I don't know about--hunting them down is part of this task.

Comment: Have you used `valgrind`?  That's my first port of call, before `gdb` for such investigations.

Comment: Our code is checked periodically with valgrind, although I'm not very familiar with it.  I thought it was only for finding memory leaks(?)  What I'm looking for here seems to be bloated, but not leaky.

Comment: `valgrind` is the container tool; you can check for leaks using the `memcheck` component, but its toolset does much more.  It's pretty much a plugin architecture.  I'm not sure whether there's a sub-tool that does what you want, but it's certainly worth checking.  See blog post ["Valgrind is *NOT* a leak checker"](http://maintainablecode.logdown.com/posts/245425-valgrind-is-not-a-leak-checker).

Comment: It's possible that you want to run `valgrind` with the [`Massif`](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) tool.

Comment: valgrind and massif is a good lead; I got a ton of information.  But here's a new question:  the memory usage reported by massif (mostly heap; a tiny percentage is stack memory) is only about 30% of what top shows.  I don't know if massif is underreporting or top is overreporting.

Comment: I'm not sure whether `massif` tracks use of `mmap()` and the like (I've not actually used it myself).  This looks like a candidate for a new question in itself.

Comment: The answer to that last question is:  it does, optionally. _Furthermore, a client program may use these lower-level system calls directly to allocate memory. By default, Massif does not measure these. Nor does it measure the size of code, data and BSS segments. Therefore, the numbers reported by Massif may be significantly smaller than those reported by tools such as top that measure a program's total size in memory._ [link](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html)

Comment: [precise link](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html#ms-manual.not-measured) :-)

Answer (score 1):

gdb, left to its own devices, will not affect the memory use of your program, though a run under gdb may differ from a standalone run for other reasons.

However, this also depends on the way you use gdb.  If you are just setting simple breakpoints, stepping, and printing things, then you are ok.  But sometimes, to evaluate an expression, gdb will allocate memory in the inferior.  For example, if you have a breakpoint condition like `strcmp(arg, "string") == 0`, then gdb will allocate memory for that string constant.  There are other cases like this as well.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is in several parts because there were several things going on:

1. Valgrind with the Massif module (a memory profiler) was much more helpful than `gdb` for this problem.  Sometimes a quick look with the debugger works, sometimes it doesn't.  http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html
2. `top` is a poor tool for profiling memory usage because it only reports virtual memory allocations, which in this case were about 3x the actual heap memory usage.  Virtual memory is mapped and made available by the Unix kernel when a process asks for a memory block, but it's not necessarily used.  The underlying system call is `mmap()`.  I still don't know how to check the block size.  `top` can only tell you what the Unix kernel knows about your memory consumption, which isn't enough to be helpful.  Don't use it (or the memory files under /proc/) to do detailed memory profiling.
3. Memory allocation when stepping out of a function was caused by autolocks--that's a thread lock class whose destructor releases the lock when it goes out of scope.  Then a different thread goes into action and allocates some memory, leaving the operator (me) mystified.  Non-repeatability is probably because some threads were waiting for external resources like Internet connections.